# How return custom errors in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, apollo

Having a mongoose model is it possible to add error handling directly to the model using `.on('error)` listener?

My goal is to add custom error messages to the incoming errors depending on their origin. Also I was thinking about changing error messages to make them more user friendly.

```
this.model.on('error', function(error) {
  if (someCondition)
    error = new ApolloError('Custom message', 'NOT_FOUND')
   return error;
});
```

Basically, I want to to receive an error with a code `NOT_FOUND` and a custom message whenever mongoose throws an error that satisfies some condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with the following solution, which is to use `toApolloError` util found in `apollo-server-errors`

```
this.model.on('error', function(error) {
  toApolloError(error, 'USER_INPUT_ERROR');
});
```